# how to remove cookie or make it expire manually during urllib2 grasp web page with python

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

i using python for auto login a website. but after it login, it saved the cookie. but when i using other user to login, it said i have login already, so 
is there any method to remove this cookie in code ?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.login_url = "http://bbs.sysu.edu.cn/ajax/login"
    self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)'
    self.headers = {'User-Agent': self.user_agent}
    self.cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
    self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookie))
    self.pattern = re.compile(r'"success":"(\d)"')
    self.guess=False

def login_test(self):
        postdata = urllib.urlencode({'userid': 'yagamil', 'passwd': 'javalinux'})
        req = urllib2.Request(self.login_url, data=postdata, headers=self.headers)
        result = self.opener.open(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `CookieJar.clear()` or `CookieJar.clear_session_cookies()` to remove the existing cookie. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#module-cookielib for details.